# Is there a collection of images (GUI - interface) program or web page available for programmers / developers games?

Tags: xna, graphics, interface

I would like to add a GUI in my basic XNA games.
Before starting work on "Photoshop" or "Illustrator". I wanted to ask you the following question:
Do you know of a website or other resource program offering a graphics collection ? Oriented (GUI - interface) free preference available to developers ?

Comment: https://creativemarket.com

Comment: "Where can I find free assets" is off topic for the site.  See the [faq].

Comment: Annoyed this is closed - votes say otherwise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[OpenGameArt has a few](http://opengameart.org/art-search-advanced?keys=&field_art_type_tid%5B%5D=9&field_art_tags_tid_op=and&field_art_tags_tid=ui&name=&sort_by=created&sort_order=DESC&Collection=). Just search for tags like 'UI', 'Menu' or something like that. [Roencia has some](http://roencia.com/interfacegraphics.html) as well. I believe the same will be true for all sites that offer some kind of graphics for developers to use.

Comment: you have really helped me! I searched long found nothing .. Do you know other websites like this? I add that in your reply

Comment: Not many more, sorry. There is http://freegamearts.tuxfamily.org/, but they seem more focused on Textures rather than 2D art. Just google for something like "free game graphics" or something like that or search for questions on that topic here on SE - I'm sure there are a few. That way, you should end up with a couple of decent and hopefully legal sources.

Comment: I'd also like to add in the SpriteLib http://www.widgetworx.com/widgetworx/portfolio/spritelib.html and Incomptech has some free music: http://incompetech.com/

And this guy makes good music :) http://www.lynnemusic.com/index.html